# Matrix graphic representation

Tags: diagrams, matrices

I was wondering if there is a method in LaTeX to create matrix representations like the one in the figure

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The [Ti*k*Z](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package might help. Or the `picture` mode of LaTeX.